# How to pass columns as comma separated parameters in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with thousands of columns that I would like to pass to `greatest` function without specifying column names individually. How can I do that?

As an example, I have `df` with 3 columns, that I am passing to `greatest`, each by specifying `df.x, df.y..` and so on.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, 4, 3)], ['x', 'y', 'z'])
>>> df.select(greatest(df.x,df.y,df.z).alias('greatest')).show()
+--------+
|greatest|
+--------+
|       4|
+--------+
```

In the above example I had only 3 columns, but if it were in thousands, it is impossible to mention each one of them. Couple of things I tried didn't work.  I am missing some crucial python...

```
df.select(greatest(",".join(df.columns)).alias('greatest')).show()
ValueError: greatest should take at least two columns

df.select(greatest(",".join(df.columns),df[0]).alias('greatest')).show()
u"cannot resolve 'x,y,z' given input columns: [x, y, z];"

df.select(greatest([c for c in df.columns],df[0]).alias('greatest')).show()
Method col([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist
```

Comment: use `pandas`. You can use `apply()` with pandas to get max value from each row (if that is what you looking for)

Comment: Haven't tried this one but it would make sense: `df.select(greatest(*[col(c) for c in df.columns]).alias('greatest')).show()`

Comment: @mkaran - It works. But what does the `*` mean here?

Comment: The `*` unpacks the list so that the `greatest` is called with positional arguments instead of a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`greatest` [supports](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=greatest#pyspark.sql.functions.greatest) positional arguments*

> `pyspark.sql.functions.greatest(*cols)`

(this is why you can `greatest(df.x,df.y,df.z)`) so just

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, 4, 3)], ['x', 'y', 'z'])
df.select(greatest(*df.columns))
```

---

* Quoting [Python glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#argument), positional argument is

> - ... an argument that is not a keyword argument. Positional arguments can appear at the beginning of an argument list and/or be passed as elements of an iterable preceded by *. For example, 3 and 5 are both positional arguments in the following calls:
>
>   ```
>   complex(3, 5)
>   complex(*(3, 5))
>   ```

Furthermore:

- [*args and **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3394835/8371915)
- [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36901/8371915)

Comment: `*cols` or `*df.columns` - Does it return a list or comma separated columns as expected by `greatest`?  I am always getting confused with it.